# Clips defRule defined successfully but does not fire with other defrules

Tags: computer-science, clips

Here is my code the first Defrule fires "get-patientnationalic" but the second one called "fever" does not
I am trying to make a clips program that test symptoms from the user and gives a diagnosis for their illness if any
this is a uni project and i have a deadline closing in but i can't get this bit to run

```
(deftemplate patient 
   (slot name)
   (slot fever))
   
(defrule get-patientnationalic
   =>
   (printout t "What is your national-IC? " crlf) 
   (bind ?nationalic (readline))
   (assert (patients's-nationalic ?nationalic)))
 
(defrule get-patientgender
   =>
   (printout t "What is your gender?" crlf) 
   (bind ?gender (readline))
   (assert (patient's-gender ?gender)))
    
(defrule fever
   (or (fever ?n)
       (fever ?n))
   ?patient <- (patient (name ?name))
   =>
   (printout t crlf "Does "?name" has fever? (yes/no)" crlf)
   (printout t " Answer: ")
   (bind ?fever (lowcase (readline)))
   (if (eq ?fever yes)
      then
      (bind ?fever y)
      else 
      (if (eq ?fever no)
         then 
         (bind ?fever n)))
   (assert (fever ?fever))
   (modify ?patient (fever ?fever)))
```

Answer (score 0):

The conditions of your fever rule can't be matched because no patient fact exists and the fever fact required by the rule is only asserted by the same rule. Just modify your code accordingly:

```
         CLIPS (6.4 2/9/21)
CLIPS> 
(deftemplate patient 
   (slot name)
   (slot gender (default unknown))
   (slot fever (default unknown))
   (slot IC (default unknown)))
CLIPS>    
(defrule get-patient-name
   =>
   (printout t "What is your name? ") 
   (bind ?name (readline))
   (assert (patient (name ?name))))
CLIPS>    
(defrule get-patient-nationalic
   ?patient <- (patient (IC unknown))
   =>
   (printout t "What is your national-IC? ") 
   (bind ?nationalic (readline))
   (modify ?patient (IC ?nationalic)))
CLIPS>  
(defrule get-patient-gender
   ?patient <- (patient (gender unknown))
   =>
   (printout t "What is your gender? ") 
   (bind ?gender (readline))
   (modify ?patient (gender ?gender)))
CLIPS>     
(defrule fever
   ?patient <- (patient (name ?name) (fever unknown))
   =>
   (printout t "Does " ?name " has fever? (yes/no) ")
   (bind ?fever (lowcase (readline)))
   (if (eq ?fever yes)
      then
      (bind ?fever y)
      else 
      (if (eq ?fever no)
         then 
         (bind ?fever n)))
   (modify ?patient (fever ?fever)))
CLIPS> (reset)
CLIPS> (run)
What is your name? Fred
What is your national-IC? US
What is your gender? male
Does Fred has fever? (yes/no) yes
CLIPS> (facts)
f-1     (patient (name "Fred") (gender "male") (fever "yes") (IC "US"))
For a total of 1 fact.
CLIPS>
```